# How to select last row in ttk.treeview python?

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

```
    def row_selection(event = None):
        idlist = product_table.get_children()
        if idlist:
            product_table.selection_set(idlist[0])
            product_table.focus(idlist[0])
            product_table.focus_force()
```

This is the function I used to select the first row and how to select the last row of table.

Comment: Did you try `product_table.selection_set(idlist[-1])`.?

Comment: got it!, thank you. @acw1668